# Formatting a byte slice in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, formatting

Using Rust, I want to take a slice of bytes from a vec and display them as hex, on the console, I can make this work using the itertools format function, and println!, *but I cannot figure out how it works*, here is the code, simplified...

```
use itertools::Itertools;

// Create a vec of bytes
let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];

... fill the vec with some data, doesn't matter how, I'm reading from a socket ...

// Create a slice into the vec
let bytes = &buf[..5];

// Print the slice, using format from itertools, example output could be: 30 27 02 01 00
println!("{:02x}", bytes.iter().format(" "));
```

(as an aside, I realize I can use the much simpler itertools join function, but in this case I don't want the default 0x## style formatting, as it is somewhat bulky)

How on earth does this work under the covers? I know itertools format is creating a "Format" struct, and I can see the source code here, https://github.com/rust-itertools/itertools/blob/master/src/format.rs , but I am none the wiser. I suspect the answer has to do with "macro_rules! impl_format" but that is just about where my head explodes.

Can some Rust expert explain the magic? I hate to blindly copy paste code without a clue, am I abusing itertools, maybe there a better, simpler way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect the answer has to do with "macro_rules! impl_format" but that is just about where my head explodes.

The `impl_format!` macro is used to implement the various formatting traits.

```
impl_format!{Display Debug
             UpperExp LowerExp UpperHex LowerHex Octal Binary Pointer}
```

The author has chosen to write a macro because the implementations all look the same. The way repetitions work in macros means that macros can be very helpful even when they are used only once (here, we could do the same by invoking the macro once for each trait, but that's not true in general).

Let's expand the implementation of `LowerHex` for `Format` and look at it:

```
impl<'a, I> fmt::LowerHex for Format<'a, I>
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: fmt::LowerHex,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.format(f, fmt::LowerHex::fmt)
    }
}
```

The `fmt` method calls another method, `format`, defined in the same module.

```
impl<'a, I> Format<'a, I>
    where I: Iterator,
{
    fn format<F>(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter, mut cb: F) -> fmt::Result
        where F: FnMut(&I::Item, &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result,
    {
        let mut iter = match self.inner.borrow_mut().take() {
            Some(t) => t,
            None => panic!("Format: was already formatted once"),
        };

        if let Some(fst) = iter.next() {
            cb(&fst, f)?;
            for elt in iter {
                if self.sep.len() > 0 {
                    f.write_str(self.sep)?;
                }
                cb(&elt, f)?;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

`format` takes two arguments: the formatter (`f`) and a formatting function (`cb` for callback). The formatting function here is `fmt::LowerHex::fmt`. This is the `fmt` method from the `LowerHex` trait; how does the compiler figure out which `LowerHex` implementation to use? It's inferred from `format`'s type signature. The type of `cb` is `F`, and `F` must implement `FnMut(&I::Item, &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result`. Notice the type of the first argument: `&I::Item` (`I` is the type of the iterator that was passed to `format`). `LowerHex::fmt`' signature is:

```
fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result;
```

For any type `Self` that implements `LowerHex`, this function will implement `FnMut(&Self, &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result`. Thus, the compiler infers that `Self == I::Item`.

One important thing to note here is that the formatting attributes (e.g. the `02` in your formatting string) are stored in the `Formatter`. Implementations of e.g. `LowerHex` will use methods such as [`Formatter::width`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.width) to retrieve an attribute. The trick here is that *the same formatter is used to format multiple values* (with the same attributes).

In Rust, methods can be called in two ways: using method syntax and using function syntax. These two functions are equivalent:

```
use std::fmt;

pub fn method_syntax(f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    use fmt::LowerHex;

    let x = 42u8;
    x.fmt(f)
}

pub fn function_syntax(f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    let x = 42u8;
    fmt::LowerHex::fmt(&x, f)
}
```

When `format` is called with `fmt::LowerHex::fmt`, this means that `cb` refers to `fmt::LowerHex::fmt`. `format` must use function call because there's no guarantee that the callback is even a method!

---

> am I abusing itertools

Not at all; in fact, this is precisely how `format` is meant to be used.

> maybe there a better, simpler way to go about this

There are simpler ways, sure, but using `format` is very efficient because it doesn't allocate dynamic memory.